# Does Adobe Bridge store the difference of files or the whole version if used with CMIS?

Tags: version-control, adobe, alfresco, difference, cmis

I'm using Alfresco CMIS with Adobe Drive and Adobe Bridge to manage versioning of Illustrator, Photoshop and InDesign files.

My question is: If I have a PSD file (say 50MB) that has 3 versions, is it stored on repository as three files, each 50MB? Or only the difference of files is stored in the repository?

Answer (score 3):

How data is stored is not covered by the spec and hence dependent on the server implementation.

Alfresco for example stores the full content byte sequence for every version. I guess it is fairly safe to assume other implementations do the same thing. One reason here is that storing changes only is complex and time consuming, unless the file type you are dealing with has special characteristics known in advance.